# Build a distribution file for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils

I am learning python am stuck at building a distribution file.python used is 2.7

I have created the `setup.py` file. But I don't know how to make a distribution?

Here is my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(

  name         ='nester',
  version      ='1.0.0',
  py_modules   = ['nester'],
  author       ='amit',
  author_email ='amit@yahoo.com',
  url          ='http://www.google.com',
  description  ='a simple nested loops',
)
```

On running `C:\Python27\nester\setup.py sdist` on the command prompt I get the following error message:

```
error : [Error 5] Access is denied :C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\\RemoteApp and Desktop...
```

Sometimes something else but it is Error 5

Please let me know how to solve it..

sorry i have edited my command which i have given it is `C:\Python27\nester\setup.py sdist`
on running above command i get error 5

Comment: Run: `python setup.py sdist`.

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll delete mine and vote yours up

Comment: hi Simeon sorry i worte wrong command which i gave, i have edited my command, please have a look on command i am giving and i get error 5 access denied.

Answer (score 0):

`"C:\Python27\nester\python" setup.py sdist`?

Comment: hi hd1 sorry i worte wrong command which i gave, i have edited my command, please have a look on command i am giving and i get error 5 access denied.